# How to structure Data Objects in C# Web API to avoid FE issues

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net, data-structures, webapi

I have an assignment for a C# course I am doing - basically create a To Do app with an associated FE, backend C# Web API. I've managed to finish the Web API and there's bonus marks available for creating a system where you can have multiple users who could login from different devices and also have different Lists - say "Work" and "Personal". So I've created a User Object and To Do List Object. Since they're all linked and I'm using EFCore, I've structured them like this:

```
public class ToDo
{
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string? Name { get; set; }
public string? Description { get; set; }
public bool? InProgress { get; set; }
public bool? IsComplete { get; set; }
public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
public ToDoList? ToDoList { get; set; }
public Guid? ToDoListId{ get; set; }
}
```

The To Do List object:

```
public class ToDoList
{
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string? Title { get; set; }
public List<ToDo>? ToDos { get; set; } // Each to-do list contains multiple to-dos
// Foreign Key to User
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
public User? User { get; set; }
}
```

And the User object:

```
public class User
{
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string? Name { get; set; }
public string? Email { get; set; }
public string? Password { get; set; }
public string? ProfilePhotoUrl { get; set; } // Store the URL to the user's profile photo
public List<ToDoList>? ToDoLists { get; set; } // A user can have multiple to-do lists
}
```

Basic relationship being -> A User can have multiple To Do Lists -> Which can have multiple To Do Objects.

I've implemented this on my backend and tested it with Swagger. It works fine but when I try to add a To Do Object with an associated To Do List, Swagger says the data object I need to send should look like this:

```
{
"id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
"name": "string",
"description": "string",
"inProgress": true,
"isComplete": true,
"created": "2023-10-26T06:43:42.157Z",
"toDoList": {
"id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
"title": "string",
"toDos": [
"string"
],
"userId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
"user": {
"id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
"name": "string",
"email": "string",
"password": "string",
"profilePhotoUrl": "string",
"toDoLists": [
"string"
]
}
},
"toDoListId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
}
```

Similarly for a To Do List object Swagger says the data structure should look like this:

```
{
"id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
"title": "string",
"toDos": [
{
"id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
"name": "string",
"description": "string",
"inProgress": true,
"isComplete": true,
"created": "2023-10-26T06:43:42.167Z",
"toDoList": "string",
"toDoListId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
}
],
"userId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
"user": {
"id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
"name": "string",
"email": "string",
"password": "string",
"profilePhotoUrl": "string",
"toDoLists": [
"string"
]
}
}
```

The problem I have is - on the FE my plan was:

When a User logs in, their User ID is saved somewhere - it'll probably be in React so global state perhaps.

When they load the main page, the request for their ToDoLists will include that User ID. The controller should look for all To Do Lists associated with that User ID and return them to the User. Ideally the only thing the List object should have is the title of the To Do Items, not all the details about them.

If they then want to look at specific To Do Items, they can click on the item for example and be taken to another page where they can see all the detail about it.

The problem here is with the data structures I have now, creating a To Do Item requires a bunch of details about the User which don't seem necessary. Similarly, creating a To Do list requires all the To Do items from the start which doesn't make since seeing as it'll be empty when it is created.

So my question is, how would you approach this issue? What's the best way to fix this or have I approached this incorrectly to start with? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what the EF Core entities have to do with the application's UI flow. They don't affect it. There's no reason to use the database types as UI types or API DTOs (they're not the same thing) either. In fact, they're almost always different.

Comment: A [famous tweet](https://twitter.com/mamund/status/767212233759657984) by the author of [RESTful Web API Patterns and Practices Cookboo](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/restful-web-api/9781098106737/) says: `remember, when designing your #WebAPI, your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model #API360`. It's definitely not your React state model

Comment: I guess what I’m trying to ask is - since my api is expecting data in the form above, how do I avoid having a structure where I am sending superfluous data

Comment: All the more reason to use different types for different operations

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to solve this problem. But in my opinion, this is how you should design your application architecture.

Since you have logged in users only, we can safely assume that the user is already in the system. So try using the restful pattern where all todos are owned by a user. so design your apis to look like `/users/:userid/todos/:todoid`. So instead of sending all these redundant data, you can just post the todo entity to a users todos enpoint. Basically the principle is to maintain the FE lean and dumb, and ensure data integrity using BE.

PS: Reading up on HATEOAS would give you a lot of insight.

Comment: Hmm yeah I can see that - would you then have the ToDoList ID on the ToDoList object that gets sent to this new endpoint?

Comment: my recommendation is that you post it to the `/users/:userid/todos` endpoint and generate the id from the BE. Thats how rest works. But you can do it the other way too as long as you can ensure data integrity.